# cgi.FieldStorage remains empty

Tags: python, cgi, wsgi

i am trying to set up a possibility to upload xml files using mod_wsgi. to do so i build a formular like this one:

```
 <form action="upload.py" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input name="file" type="file" accept="text/xml"><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="upload">
 </form>
```

and a file `upload.py`:

```
 ..
 form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=environ['wsgi.input'], 
                         environ=environ, 
                         keep_blank_values=True)
 fileitem = form['file']
 ..
```

however, this gives me a keyerror while accessing 'file' in form. printing `environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)` shows:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryeplWkFZe2clFMtgf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.xml"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
....
```

as consequence, wsgi.input seems to be valid. debugging exposes that `cgi.FieldStorage() = FieldStorage(None, None, [])`. have you an idea where the problem may be? am i missing something?

Comment: You should really use a framework instead. Bottle and Flask are both tiny, and are easy to use.

Comment: I decided to use Bottle. Nevertheless, the problem here was the HTML-code of the <form>. I have no idea what exactly caused the problem, although rewriting the <form> part solved the error.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same and placing the lines:

```
request_body_size = int( environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH') )
print environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)
```

*before* calling the `cgi.FieldStorage()` with `wsgi.input` as an argument, it shows the body. Apparently that `wsgi.input` fileIO-object gets consumed inside the FS and one cannot read it after that. I tried to read it twice before using it with FS and the same happens, only first works.

Edit: Yes, and it gets even worse, wsgi.input does not implement .seek() method to wind it back to beginning. Only reasonable way is to make a copy of it into io.BytesIO class instance and feed *that* into FS. It can be wound back with .seek() later, whatever. Note that one could use StringIO but that breaks if you're uploading binary files.